# How to define an observation space with one int value and 2 double values in OpenAI gym?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have an environment in open AI gym, where the observation space is like [12,12.5,16.7], one value is discrete and the other two are continues, how can I define this in Gym?

I have tried to use the multi-discrete and discrete but it doesn't cover the continuous space, and I also tried box but the first integer one was problematic.

Comment: Did you found any answer to this?

Comment: @your_boy_gorja No. I ended up assuming Box (as np.asarray) for all and then converting the first entry  to integer. (So far it seems like it's working fine and no syntax or logical error)

Comment: Cool Thanks. That's the wat to make RL work sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

In reinforcement learning you usually want to normalize the observations in the range 0-1 (especially if you are using neural networks as function approximators). Therefore, it makes sense to use Boxes in the range 0-1.